# Extendable background image based on its child

Tags: android, react-native

I want a background image to be extendable based on its child.
I am using `ImageBackground` and `Text`.

```
<ImageBackground>
  <Text/>
</ImageBackground>
```

Is there any way to do it?
Here are some screenshots

[English version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dur5q.png)

[German version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuEAy.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 9-Patch files

1. In Android Studio, right-click the PNG image you'd like to create a
   NinePatch image from, then click Create 9-patch file.
2. Type a file
   name for your NinePatch image, and click OK. Your image will be
   created with the .9.png file extension.
3. Double-click your new
   NinePatch file to open it in Android Studio. Your workspace will now
   open. The left pane is your drawing area, in which you can edit the
   lines for the stretchable patches and content area. The right pane
   is the preview area, where you can preview your graphic when
   stretched.
4. Click within the 1-pixel perimeter to draw the lines that define the
   stretchable patches and (optional) content area. Right-click (or
   hold Shift and click, on Mac) to erase previously drawn lines.
5. When done, click File > Save to save your changes.

Check this link for the whole article: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/draw9patch

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have updated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [9 Patch image](https://tekeye.uk/android/examples/ui/android-9-patch-image-files) for this purpose. Check [this](https://www.dev2qa.com/android-nine-patch-image-example/) for steps on how to create a 9 patch image.